# Running process with nohup; process still running after disconnecting from terminal session but file not getting written to anymore

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'm trying to keep scripts that have long run-times going over night so we can see the results in the morning but the issue is that when invoking the script as follows:

**nohup python script.py > logs/logfoo.txt &**

I disconnect from the server and log back into to make sure it's still running but the strange thing is that it is running but it doesn't seem to be making any progress and write any output to the log after I disconnect from my terminal session. I can see the process running after running:

**ps -ef | grep "python script.py"**

Any ideas on why this may be happening?

Comment: If you try `nohup stdbuf -o0 python script.py > logs/logfoo.txt &`. Does it work for you?

Comment: I'll give it a go and let ya know :)

Comment: How much output should it be generating? Is it possible to assume that it is just in a quite part of the job?

Comment: The frequency of output is certainly variable but I've tried looking to see if changes had been written to the file after 30 or minutes one time and after roughly 1 hour on another occasion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: Much thanks to hek2mgl for suggesting running the script as:

**nohup stdbuf -o0 python script.py > logs/logfoo.txt &**

This indeed solved the issue; script continued execution and verified it was making progress by running stat on the file continuously and seeing the modified timestamp updated according and also viewed in VIM occasionally to check as well. Thanks again!